# Morse Code via iPhone LED

Tags: iphone, led, morse-code

I have coded an App that can convert normal Text like : "Hello my Name is XY"

into points and strokes ( ..-. ; --.- ; . ; - ; etc etc)

Now I want to Convert these points and stroke into light flashes with the lenght of 0.3 sec for points an 0.6 seconds for strokes. also there is a pause with the length of a point after each point or stroke, a double pause after each Word, and a tripple pause/break after each sentences.

The breaks are also implied into my code.

The problem is now that the light strokes aren't different enough.

Because the Idea behind it is to convert the Light flashes via an Arduino Duo and a fototransistor back to Text.

Here is the Code Passage for the Light converting Process:

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender{
```

// Converting Text to morsecode etc

```
float needTime;
NSString *string = plotter;
for (int d = 0;d < [string length]; d++) {
    NSString *punktoderstrich = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(d, 1)];
    if ([punktoderstrich isEqualToString:@"."]) {
        needTime = needTime + 0.4f;
        [self performSelector:@selector(playpunkt) withObject:nil afterDelay:needTime];
    }
    if ([punktoderstrich isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
        needTime = needTime + 1.0f;
        [self performSelector:@selector(playstrich) withObject:nil afterDelay:needTime];
    }
    if ([punktoderstrich isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        needTime = needTime + 0.4f;
        [self performSelector:@selector(playpause) withObject:nil afterDelay:needTime];

    }
    if ([punktoderstrich isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
        needTime = needTime + 0.3f;
        [self performSelector:@selector(playpause) withObject:nil afterDelay:needTime];

    }
}

- (void)torchAn {
[captureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
[captureDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[captureDevice setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
[captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
- (void)torchAus {
[captureDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
[captureDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
[captureDevice setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
[captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
-(void)playstrich{
// AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (outSystemSoundID2);
[self torchAn];
//[self performSelector:@selector(torchAus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8f];
}

-(void)playpunkt{
//AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (outSystemSoundID1);
[self torchAn];
//[self performSelector:@selector(torchAus) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4f];
}

- (void)playpause{
// AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (outSystemSoundID3);
[self performSelector:@selector(torchAus) /*withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4f*/];
}
```

Like You see I also imported sound files (short and Long) but the Main target is to give a right light signal out.

My Problems:

Short lights are mostly okay, exept the first when the LED is firstly flashing.
Long light signals aren't really longer. Sometimes I get equal results when I'm recording them.

And after a Long light should light up the following short ones aren't short as normal.. hm..

After I had commented the Part with the sounds out, the whole process became more stable.
I also moved the Part (turning LED OFF) from the sign it self to the breaks.

I hope somebody can give me some tipps or so :)

Greets from Germany!

P.S.: My divice is an iPhone 4s (with torch ^^)

Comment: The torch isn't really meant to be turned on and off quickly in this manner, so it may never have the kind of precision you want for these short bursts. Have you thought about using the iPhone screen instead, and flashing that between all-white and all-black? That might still put out enough illumination for your sensor to detect.

Comment: the detection from the sensor has a value from 0 to 1024.

When I hold the torch direct in I get something between 180 - 280

When I use only the display with full light possibility I only get 13-17 which is too less. Because if you are in an room where stray light is already there the value is already above this. So I would get pretty many wrong decryptions.. But thanks for your opinion! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Brad said the iPhone flash needs a few ms to turn on. If you still want to use it the only possibility would be (in my eyes) to change your protocol and give the single signals more time.

This slows down your transmission but on the receiver-side you could define some confidence intervals (like plus-minus 2 seconds). Maybe a human beeing would not understand your morse code because it could be too slow (but maybe they will), a machine like the iPhone as a receiver would be perfectly able to understand it.

You have to play around with the time intervals to find the shortest ones that are working.

Greetings from GER.

Comment: thanks you both. I played now a little bit with the intervalls and recognized two things.

The first sign is only half there because I need to turn the torch on. Maybe I add a long sign there (longer than a stroke) to say the opposide I'm starting now and initialize the torch. After that the short signs do working perfect also after pauses or long strongs.

The real problem is from point to stroke.. because strokes alone like " - - - " are working perfectly only " . - " makes problems..

The break before the - starts is too long and "steeling" the time from the stroke!

Comment: Extend your intervals again to start debugging! ( > 5 sec)

Comment: like I thought the Problem is still there. I set the point to 1 sec and the stroke to 2 seconds and the break to 1 sec. the stroke has still the describted problem and I don't know how to solve it..

Comment: Try setting the break a lot longer than the rest (like 5 seconds)!